# pull images from twitter API on processing 3

Tags: image, twitter, processing, twitter4j

I am quite new to this so please bear with me. I am trying to use a keyword search to pull images from twitter using twitter4j. I want it to show the images positioned randomly on the screen in a loop.

This code I have below is a combination of different ones I have found online. Its currently finding tweets using these keywords and showing them in the console, however, it is not displaying them on the screen and I’m not sure why…

Another thing is that I think it is doing a live stream from twitter so pulling tweets immediately at the time the code is run, so I am not getting lots of results when I put in an obscure keyword,  I want it to search for the last 100 tweets with images using the keyword so that I get more results

I’d really appreciate all the help I can get! thank you

```js
///////////////////////////// Config your setup here! ////////////////////////////

// { site, parse token }
String imageService[][] = {
    {
      "http://twitpic.com",
      "<img class=\"photo\" id=\"photo-display\" src=\""
    },
    {
      "http://twitpic.com",
      "<img class=\"photo\" id=\"photo-display\" src=\""
    },
    {
      "http://img.ly",
      "<img alt=\"\" id=\"the-image\" src=\""
    },
    {
      "http://lockerz.com/",
      "<img id=\"photo\" src=\""
    },
    {
      "http://instagr.am/",
      "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\""
    } {
      "http://pic.twitter.com",
      "<img id
    };

    // This is where you enter your Oauth info
    static String OAuthConsumerKey = KEY_HERE;
    static String OAuthConsumerSecret = SECRET_HERE;
    static String AccessToken = TOKEN_HERE;
    static String AccessTokenSecret = TOKEN_SECRET_HERE;
    cb.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);
    Twitter twitterInstance = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    // if you enter keywords here it will filter, otherwise it will sample

    String keywords[] = {
      "#hashtag" //sample keyword!!!!!!!!
    };

    ///////////////////////////// End Variable Config ////////////////////////////

    TwitterStream twitter = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();


    PImage img;
    boolean imageLoaded;

    void setup() {
      frameRate(10);
      size(800, 600);
      noStroke();
      imageMode(CENTER);

      connectTwitter();
      twitter.addListener(listener);
      if (keywords.length == 0) twitter.sample();
      else twitter.filter(new FilterQuery().track(keywords));
    }

    void draw() {
      background(0);
      if (imageLoaded) image(img, width / 5, height / 5);
      //image(loadImage((status.getUser().getImage())), (int)random(width*.45), height-(int)random(height*.4));
    }

    // Initial connection
    void connectTwitter() {
      twitter.setOAuthConsumer(OAuthConsumerKey, OAuthConsumerSecret);
      AccessToken accessToken = loadAccessToken();
      twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    }

    // Loading up the access token
    private static AccessToken loadAccessToken() {
      return new AccessToken(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
    }

    // This listens for new tweet
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

      //@Override
      public void onStatus(Status status) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
      }

      //@Override
      public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
        System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
      }

      //@Override
      public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
        System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
      }

      //@Override
      public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
        System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
      }

      //@Override
      public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
        System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
      }

      //@Override
      public void onException(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    };
    public void onStatus(Status status) {

      String imgUrl = null;
      String imgPage = null;

      // Checks for images posted using twitter API

      if (status.getMediaEntities() != null) {
        imgUrl = status.getMediaEntities()[0].getMediaURL().toString();
      }
      // Checks for images posted using other APIs
      else {
        if (status.getURLEntities().length > 0) {
          if (status.getURLEntities()[0].getExpandedURL() != null) {
            imgPage = status.getURLEntities()[0].getExpandedURL().toString();
          } else {
            if (status.getURLEntities()[0].getDisplayURL() != null) {
              imgPage = status.getURLEntities()[0].getDisplayURL().toString();
            }
          }
        }

        if (imgPage != null) imgUrl = parseTwitterImg(imgPage);
      }

      if (imgUrl != null) {

        println("found image: " + imgUrl);

        // hacks to make image load correctly

        if (imgUrl.startsWith("//")) {
          println("s3 weirdness");
          imgUrl = "http:" + imgUrl;
        }
        if (!imgUrl.endsWith(".jpg")) {
          byte[] imgBytes = loadBytes(imgUrl);
          saveBytes("tempImage.jpg", imgBytes);
          imgUrl = "tempImage.jpg";
        }

        println("loading " + imgUrl);
        img = loadImage(imgUrl);
        imageLoaded = true;
      }
    }

    public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
      System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
    }
    public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
      System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
    }
    public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
      System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
    }

    public void onException(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Twitter doesn't recognize images from other sites as media, so must be parsed manually
    // You can add more services at the top if something is missing

    String parseTwitterImg(String pageUrl) {

      for (int i = 0; i < imageService.length; i++) {
        if (pageUrl.startsWith(imageService[i][0])) {

          String fullPage = ""; // container for html
          String lines[] = loadStrings(pageUrl); // load html into an array, then move to container
          for (int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
            fullPage += lines[j] + "\n";
          }

          String[] pieces = split(fullPage, imageService[i][1]);
          pieces = split(pieces[1], "\"");

          return (pieces[0]);
        }
      }
      return (null);
    }
```

Comment: You should never post your OAuth secrets publicly: they're basically your passwords. I'll remove them from your post, but the edit history is public, so please make sure to change your secrets ASAP.

Comment: Please try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. Get one sketch working that queries Twitter to generate an array of image URLs. Create a separate sketch that takes an array of image URLs and shows those images. Start with just a single image, and get that working first. Then if you're still stuck, you can come back here and post a [mcve] showing just the step you're stuck on. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for taking them off! I've changed them now. Also thanks for explaining the break down that seems more manageable, I'll definitely try it and come back.